# Magento2 how to display video as a thumbnail image in admin grid

Tags: magento2, grid, thumbnail, custom-admin-grid

I want to display video as a thumbnail in the custom admin grid.
you can get the reference from the below screenshot.
https://i.imgur.com/UTBHZvM.png

Comment: Do you specificaly need a video ? Did you try with a GIF image ?

Comment: yes, I have tried for that specific video and Gif but it did not work so give a solution 
 the proper solution for how can I add gifs and videos.

Comment: yes, I have tried for that specific video and Gif but it did not work so give the proper solution for how can I add gifs and videos @Cladiuss